# Understanting code with greater than and less than operators

Tags: arduino, operators

I'm trying to understand this line of code.

```
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
```

It is part of ambilight.ino for Arduino and uses the FastLED library. It seems to be related to the initialization of the led stripe, but I can't understand how the < and > symbols are being used, if they are comparators or somewhat other thing...

I know a bit of coding, but this one is puzzling me.

Cheers.

I don't have many things to try, just want to understand the code.

The code is working correctly, just want to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a template, read more about templates here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

You can see the definition of the template in the FastLed library here: https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/FastLED.h#L390

Comment: Thank you. It makes much more sense now. It's strange that when our brain tries to decode something without the right prerequisites will not be able to see anything and after a small clue of how it works it suddenly make sense.